# Backdrop equivalent

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

When I'm reading ebooks, I find it quite useful to blank out everything except the reader. On the Mac, I use [Backdrop](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/15426/backdrop) to achieve this. What this app does is blank out everything (wallpaper, desktop icons, etc) apart from any on-screen windows. Is there a program that does this for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Dimming non-active Windows with Compiz

In case we run Compiz (by enabling Visual Effects in *System->Preferences->Appearance*) we have a nice feature that lets you dim anything but the active windows to any desired value.

With the following packages installed (default from >= 11.04):

- `compizconfig-settings-manager`
- `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`

you will have access to control Compiz settings by running *System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager*.

#### Choose Accessibility: ADD Helper

[image]

#### Open Tab "Misc.Options:

[image]

and push the slider for brightness to the desired value (here depicted for 20).

Comment: Thanks for that, but I appear to be missing this plugin. Is it perhaps new in 10.10? I'm running 10.04.

Comment: Never mind, I just had to install `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`.

Comment: I included this valuable additional information, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [ADD Helper](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Addhelper) Compiz plugin.  Install `compizconfig-settings-manager` package to access the [controls](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM) for it.

Comment: Voting up @Takkat's answer for having pictures.  :D

Comment: Voting up @Ben Preston's answer for having links :P